# How do you get the golden eggs in Angry Birds?

Tags: angry-birds

How do you get the golden eggs in Angry Birds? I know that you get some of them for completing all of the levels with 3 stars.  But, how do you get the others?

Answer (score 12):

[Here's a guide](http://www.playhaven.com/guides/iphone/angry-birds/golden-egg-guide/XnkXzvuUltor/) on how to get all the golden eggs. This is copy and pasted straight from the website:

> - Getting 3 stars in the first chapter
> - Getting 3 stars in the second chapter
> - In the level select screen, tap the sun
> - Watch the credits, there's one at the end
> - Within any level, go to the help screen. There's one in the white bird's help image.
> - Level 1-8, tap the unreachable chest
> - Level 2-2, break the beach ball
> - Level 4-7, at the very top right of the map (zoom out)
> - Level 5-19, it's hiding on the top right of the left tower

Comment: > I've added the spoiler tag to the question, so you could paste the info here now.

Comment: Okay, I added it in.

Comment: How to get to the help screen?

Comment: @Željko Filipin Tap the pause button in a level, and then the question mark button. If you continue through the help images, one of them has a golden egg. (Tap on it to get it.)

Answer (score 1):

As of writing there are now 31 Golden Eggs hidden in the original Angry Birds.  There is a much better guide here, http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/angry-birds-golden-eggs-walkthrough/ and it's updated any time new eggs are added.

Comment: Please summarize the linked information here, please.  That way, if the site ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it saves people a click.  The old answer may no longer be up to date, but that's an opportunity to provide one!